# Does this definition of archimedean property guarantee that a set has no infinitely large or infinitely small elements?

Tags: real-analysis

I've just read the archimedean property:

> 1. **Archimedean Property**: If $a\in \mathbb{R}$, then there's a positive integer $n$ such that:
>
> $$n>a$$
>
> Remark: The archimedean property is sometimes expressed in the
>   following equivalent way: for any positive real number $a$, there is a
>   positive integer $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<a$.

And at first contact, I wasn't understanding the purpose of the concept, and then I searched [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) and found:

> Roughly speaking, it is the property of having no infinitely large or
>   infinitely small elements.

I guess that the first given property guarantees only that there are infinite positive real numbers, I'm thinking like: for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$, there is always a positive  $n$ that is bigger than $a$ and independently of what real number is chosen, there will be always a bigger positive natural number but the property does not enforce that given $a\in \mathbb{R}$, there will always be a negative integer $n_{\tiny -}$ such that $n_{\tiny -}<a$.

I guess that it would be much better stated to say:

> If $a\in \mathbb{R}$, then there's a positive integer $n_{\tiny +}$
>   and a negative integer $n_{\tiny -}$ such that $n_{\tiny +}>a$ and
>   $n_{\tiny -}<a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every number has an additive inverse, so if there is infinitely large positive element, its inverse is an infinitely large negative.

Comment: But that's not true for $\mathbb{N}$, right?

Comment: No, but the discussion is about $\Bbb R$.

Comment: The part I'm stuck is when he says that there's a positive integer $n$.

Comment: Apparently I don't understand your question.

Comment: Now I got stuck in another thing. I'll think for a while.

Comment: Gustavo, the definition is given for positive elements only. But if there were $a\in\Bbb R$ such that for all $k\in\Bbb Z$, $a<k$ then $-a$ would be a positive real number with the property that $k<-a$ for any positive integer $k$. Therefore it is enough to require the property for positive numbers.