# How is the property of having no infinitely large or small elements derived from the original statement of the archimedean property?

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

There is already a question asked related to this.

Here's the link:[Does this definition of archimedean property guarantee that a set has no infinitely large or infinitely small elements?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/362262/831748)

That question asks that, does his/her statement guarantees the property of having no infinitely large or small elements. But there is no proper answer and I  also don't know is his/her derived statement truly guarantees the property mentioned in the wikipedia page of the Archimedean property:

> Roughly speaking, it is the property of having no infinitely large or
> infinitely small elements

My question is kind of a generalized version of that question.

From the original statement

$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$,
$\exists n \in \mathbb{N}:nx>y$

How to derive the property of having no infinitely large or infinitely small element?

*(I am not a mathematician so please don't used too advanced mathematics in the answers)*

Comment: To the readers please don't this a 7 years old properly unanswered question just like the one I mentioned in my question

Comment: What do you think about the definition of *infinitely large* element? For me, this is an element that is larger than any natural number.

Comment: @Hanul Jeon, maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My statement is based on a simpler version of the Archimedean property, which states $\forall y \in \mathbb{R} \exists n \in \mathbb{N} (n > y)$. This is easy to prove from OP's definition: we note that $|y| + 1 \in \mathbb{R}_+$ and $1 \in \mathbb{R}_+$. Then, we take some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \cdot 1 > |y| + 1$. Then $n \cdot 1 > |y| + 1 > |y| \geq y$. Then $n > y$.

What is an "infinitely large number?" We need to define this term precisely before we can answer your question.

A sensible definition of "$x$ is an infinitely large number" is $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} (|x| > n)$. Obviously, the Archimedean property immediately refutes the existence of an infinitely large $x$,  since it states that there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x| < n$.

What about an "infinitely small number"? I would define "x is infinitely small" to be the statement $|x| > 0 \land \forall n \in \mathbb{N} (|x| < \frac{1}{n})$.

There can be no infinitely small $x$. For if there were such an $x$, take some $n$ such that $n > \frac{1}{|x|}$. In that case, we would have $\frac{1}{n} < |x|$.

Comment: Why do you bring the natural numbers into your definition of infinitely large number - on the face of it, the definition should just be "bigger than every real number." What's the special relevance of *natural* numbers here, as opposed to rational, algebraic, ...?

Comment: @MatthewTowers "Infinite" means "not finite". Presumably, "finite" is related to natural numbers. That's the philosophical reason. Practically, the reason is that it doesn't matter. You can show directly that the rational numbers and algebraic numbers obey the Archimedean property. Consequently, it's logically equivalent to phrase the "infinitely large" property in terms of rational or algebraic numbers.

Comment: Thanks. This is a very good answer but can we extend your reasoning so that it can hold for the original statement of the archimedean property?and if so then how?

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar I proved that the original statement of the Archimedean property implies my statement of the property. So anything I prove from my statement also follows from the original.

Comment: @Mark Saving, oh yeah. Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewTowers: I don't know who upvoted your comment, but it is somewhat problematic. The standard way of obtaining a non-archimedean ordered field that satisfies the same first-order theory as the reals is to add a constant-symbol $c$ and the axioms $\{c>1,c>1+1,c>1+1+1,\cdots\}$, which is consistent and hence has a model $F$, in which the interpretation of $c$ is more than every (standard) natural number. On the other hand, $c$ is *not* more than every element of $F$. The key difference is that naturals embed into the reals as terms of the theory.

Comment: The point is that, if you use any FOL axiomatization of reals, then you cannot force its models to be archimedean, which means that "archimedean" is not a first-order property. So it is actually wrong to say that "$x$ is infinite" for element $x$ in a field $F$ means "$∀r{∈}ℝ\ ( |x|>r )$", since "$|x|$" refers to the absolute value of $x$ in $F$, which is **not a real**. And @MarkSaving is also not really right to say that it means "$∀r{∈}ℕ\ ( |x|>r )$". Rather, the proper definition of "$x$ is infinite" is that all the sentences in $\{x>1,x>1+1,x>1+1+1,\cdots\}$ are true in $F$.